# Symfony 4.2 Build request

Tags: sql, symfony

I'm building a request in Symfony but i have an error "$products not define". How should i do to make a good definition? Do u find another problem in my request? Any amelioration which is possible? Thank you!

```html
    public function findEtudiantPasPointer($em, $utilisateurProf, $idCours, $idDate, $idCreneau)
    {
      $query = $em->createQuery("
      SELECT u.nomUtilisateur, u.prenomUtilisateur
      FROM App\Entity\Pointage po
      LEFT JOIN App\Entity\EtudiantCours ec ON po.utilisateurEtudiant = ec.etudiant
      JOIN App\Entity\Utilisateur u ON po.utilisateurEtudiant = u.id
      JOIN App\Entity\CoursPlanning cp ON po.cours = cp.cours
      AND cp.cours = :idCours
      AND cp.plageHoraire = :idCreneau
      AND cp.dateCours = :idDate
      AND cp.cours = :idCours
      AND cp.id = po.cours
      AND ec.cours = c.id
      ")
      ->setParameter('idCours', $idCours);
      ->setParameter('idDate', $idDate);
      ->setParameter('idCreneau', $idCreneau);

      $products = $query->getResult();
      return $products;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `;` semicolon symbol:

```
  // before
  ->setParameter('idCours', $idCours)
  ->setParameter('idDate', $idDate)
  ->setParameter('idCreneau', $idCreneau)

  // after
  ->setParameter('idCours', $idCours)
  ->setParameter('idDate', $idDate)
  ->setParameter('idCreneau', $idCreneau); // <---- HERE!
```

Also in DQL there's no `ON` when joining, should be `WITH` instead. Read the [DQL's documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples) how to query related entities properly.

Comment: Thank you! But now i have this error : 
"syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)" on the line 
" ->setParameter('idDate', $idDate)". I updated the code.

Comment: I didn't tell you to put semicolon everywhere. Fix your code - use proper IDE.

Comment: Ok sry, i see, thank you. I have this strange error : 
"[Syntax Error] line 0, col 130: Error: Expected end of string, got 'ON'" now. 
My request seems to be correct... do you have an idea? :S ty

Comment: In DQL there's no `ON`. Should be `WITH`. Have you read Doctrine's documentation how to write DQL query properly?